# Email message with static Google map not displaying correctly in Gmail

Tags: c#, gmail, html-email

I am using C# code to generate an email message.

In the body of the message, I want to add a static Google map. To create the static URL, I have the following code

```
string addr = "111 Remote Drive  Cary,NC 27511";
string mapU = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + 
addr + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=color:green|") +
 addr;
```

This string mapU is added to the message body as a src for an img tag.

When the email is sent to a Google Mail account, the static image is not displayed. Inspect element on broken image has

```
<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=111+Remote+Drive++Cary%2CNC+27511%26zoom%3D14%26size%3D512x512%26maptype%3Droadmap%26sensor%3Dfalse%26markers%3Dcolor:green%7C111+Remote+Drive++Cary,NC+27511">
```

Gmail is replacing '=' with %3D, which seems to be breaking this.

Sending the exact same message to Hotmail works. The image is displayed in the correct place as expected. Hotmail is keeping '=' intact.

Any ideas what is going on with Gmail? Suggestions how this could be fixed?

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: I am having the same problem Abhi - did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your encoding is a bit off - you want to encode *individual* values, not the *entire* query string.

More importantly, Google leads here for the term "google maps static gmail", so I wanted to also offer this advice:

- To include a static map and have it show in GMail, you **must use an API key**

e.g.

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=KEY&sensor=false&size=200x200&zoom=12&markers=0,0" />
```

I wish I had the doc to support that (if it exists) or even the link to the thread where I first read it so I could give proper attribution - please edit if you know. In either case, it worked for me!

Comment: I searched high and low for quite some time as to why static maps weren't showing in Gmail, and this answer is the only place on the internet I could find the cause, which as suggested is **the maps no API key**.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for some reason the URL encode is not working correctly.. or is causing gmail to freak out about something...

Remove the encode and manually replace the & with &amp; and it should be fine..

Sorry, not the most elegant solution...

EDIT:

Actually I don't know if it matters or not... but your not encoding the first = maybe encode the entire URL after you have built it... :-)